# Calculating relative times in Tableau

Tags: aggregate, tableau-api

this should be so simple, and probably is...

I need something like this:
[finish time] - MIN([finish time]) 
or
DATEDIFF('second',MIN([finish time]), [finish time])

but, of course, I'd be mixing aggregate and non-aggregate values
so it doesn't work.

I've looked but I cannot find what should be a stupid-simple solution.

thanks,
joe

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe you are trying to compare the finish time of an entry with the minimum finish time in the table, is that correct?

The right way to calculate that is using a table calculation

```
MAX([finish time]) - WINODW_MIN(MAX([finish time])
```

Don't worry about the MAX()s, they are meant to aggregate the values only.

Now important, your worksheet should have the level of detail you need, i.e., if each entry has an unique Id, you should drag [Id] to the worksheet, together with this new calculated field, so it can work. Table calculations works with partitions made from what is there on the worksheet.